# Python: How to print this special string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I want to print `'\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xba\xda\xc1\xfa\xbd\xad'` which is a Chinese character.

```
l = ['\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xba\xda\xc1\xfa\xbd\xad']
a = [l[0].decode('utf-8')]
print(a[0])
```

But it raises this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`. I also tried `deocde('latin-1')`. But the result aren't Chinese characters.

Comment: Where did you get those bytes?

Comment: @Ryan it's form a csv file, all the values in that column are Chinese charaters as are shown in excel.

Comment: What are the correct characters for these bytes? Could you include those in the question, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
l = ['\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xba\xda\xc1\xfa\xbd\xad']
a = [l[0].decode('gb2312').encode('utf-8')]
print(a[0])
```

output:

```
中国黑龙江
```

**Update:** as Mark's advice, use `l[0].decode('gb2312')` will be sufficient.

```
l = ['\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xba\xda\xc1\xfa\xbd\xad']
a = [l[0].decode('gb2312')]
print(a[0])
```

Comment: If the terminal is configured correctly, `print(l[0].decode('gb2312'))` should be sufficient.  Printing Unicode uses the terminal's default encoding.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes, updated the answer based on your advice.